# Git pull from upsteam branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm running my project on a centos7 server. I SSH into this server.

My git on the server is setup like so:

```
git branch -a
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/new-docker
  remotes/origin/stable
  remotes/upstream/auto-close-maintenances
  remotes/upstream/dependabot/bundler/redcarpet-3.5.1
  remotes/upstream/master
  remotes/upstream/new-docker
  remotes/upstream/services-api-expansion
  remotes/upstream/stable
```

How do I pull all the changes from *remotes/upstream/stable* to my develop branch?

also I"m not really sure what the difference is between the *upstream/stable* and *remotes/origin/stable*

**UPDATE 1:**

Running

```
git fetch upstream stable
From https://github.com/.../...
 * branch            stable     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

**Update 2:**

Running

```
[server]$ git checkout develop
Already on 'develop'
[server]$ git merge upstream/stable
Already up-to-date.
```

something's gotta be wrong here...

Comment: A branch is nothing but a reference to a commit.  You need to fetch the commit that you want.  Once you have that commit, you have several options.  Perhaps you just want to rebase `develop` onto it.

Comment: You have two remotes, origin and upstream. I assume this is a fork of another git repo?

Comment: Yes @evolutionxbox that is correct.

Comment: Now the fetch has been done, it can be merged. `git checkout develop; git merge upstream/stable`

Comment: @evolutionxbox updated original question with update 2 - something must be out of whack

Comment: Then all is good. The local develop is up-to-date with stable on upstream. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I pull all the changes from remotes/upstream/stable to my develop branch?

There is no such thing as "pull changes". Git does not traffic in "changes". It traffics in commits, which are snapshots, some of which have names. `remotes/upstream/stable` and `develop` are both the names of commits. If these names represent the end commits of branches that have diverged from one another at some point in history and the idea is to play out both sets of commits since that point, that is `git merge`.

Note that `remotes/upstream/stable` is *local* — it isn't a "local branch" but it is locally held. It is a "remote-tracking" branch, but it is not remote from this repo; it lives here, not at the upstream server. So until you `git fetch upstream`, it won't necessarily contain recent commits that exist back at the upstream server.

So `git fetch` first and then you can `git merge` (or whatever it was you wanted to do).

> also I"m not really sure what the difference is between the upstream/stable and remotes/origin/stable

There isn't any difference. Git has various levels of formality for what you see and can say. Git tries to fill in the gap when you are less formal. If you say `origin/stable`, that is a bit less formal, so Git hunts around for something that you might mean and decides that you probably mean `remotes/origin/stable`. In the same way, I suppose sometimes Git might *show* you the phrase `origin/stable` even when `remotes/origin/stable` is meant.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for old CentOS (and RH7) systems, on which the Git supplied is ancient.  Run `git --version`; if the output says you have Git 1.7, or 1.8 before 1.8.4 (e.g., 1.8.3.1), you have this kind of truly ancient Git.<sup>1</sup>

Here, `git fetch upstream stable` *fails to update `upstream/stable`* so that `git merge upstream/stable` does no good.  To fix the problem, use **any one** of the following:

1. Run `git fetch upstream` instead of `git fetch upstream stable`.  This will fetch everything *and* update everything, including `upstream/stable`.  Then proceed as you were doing before, by merging `upstream/stable`.  Note: this depends on your settings for `upstream`.  In particular it should not be a single-branch remote.
2. Run `git fetch upstream +refs/heads/stable:refs/remotes/upstream/stable`.  This will force `git fetch` to update `upstream/stable`.  (This works even if `upstream` is set up as a single-branch remote, and is needed even in modern Git if `upstream` is set up as a single-branch remote.)  Then proceed as before.
3. Run `git fetch upstream stable`, but then run `git merge FETCH_HEAD` instead of `git merge upstream/stable`.  This works around the ancient Git's failure to update `upstream/stable`.  It works regardless of whether `upstream` is a single-branch remote.
4. Upgrade Git.  With a modern Git, your Git will behave in the modern way.

---

<sup>1</sup>This output:

> ```
> git fetch upstream stable
> From https://github.com/.../...
>  * branch            stable     -> FETCH_HEAD
> ```

also indicates that you have an ancient Git; a modern one would list `upstream/stable` instead of, or in addition to, `FETCH_HEAD` here.